# How do I make these move as one

Tags: animation

[image: Model of my arms]

Both arms have this same issue and the forearm bone for the under and over sleeve has the same pull for the buttons and sleeve, I dont know how I could get these to move as one.

Comment: make sure that the weight painting is good, maybe use a Mask modifier to hide a part of the under sleeve. You could also try a Mesh Deform modifier, I'm not sure it's the best for arms though. But maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/ZR64Lo0M

Comment: Aside from  fixing as below, would recommend removing, or masking,   the shirt where it cannot be seen when the jacket is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weight is not good, for example the upper arm bone influences the lower arm mesh, you need to use a brush *Blend* type > *Subtrac*t to correct and it seems to work.

[image]